# Need to have Nuget package with transitive reference overridden by local reference for unit test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

In my Solution, I have an unit test project A.

My test project A has a direct nuget reference to package B witch include a transitive reference to nuget package C.

My test project A has also a local reference to local project C'.

So, in my project A, I have both local reference to C' an nuget reference to C.

And this is the nuget applied and not the local reference...

I want to apply local reference for my tests.

To resume :

- A (unit test) > B (direct nuget) > C (transisive nuget)
- A (unit test) > C' (local reference)

My project is in .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: Sorry, finally I resolved it by erasing all references, reboot VS and add a reference to my local project...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Since your workaround is similar as mine. When you use the lcoal dll under `hintpath` which means that you have directly referenced the local project. Anyway, thanks for sharing the solution with us. `I have added your solution into the answer and you can mark it so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues:)` Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your has used [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) in **Project A**.

And it seems that you have used both **nuget package** and **ProjectReference** for Project **C** on `xxx.csproj` file of Project **A**.

Like this:

```
 <Reference Include="ProjectB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>xxx\ProjectB.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="ProjectC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>xxx\ProjectC.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>

 <ProjectReference Include="C:\xxx\ProjectC.csproj">
        <Name>ProjectC</Name>
 </ProjectReference>
```

**In fact**, `transisive nuget` has a higher priority than `ProjectReference`. And when you references a same dll by these two ways, VS will always use `transisive nuget`.

To solve it, please check these two suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** Just change the `hintpath` of the nuget package `ProjectC` to the local project's dll.

```
<Reference Include="ProjectC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>xxx\local path\ProjectC.dll(use the dll of the local project C)</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**2)** Or you should delete or comment out the nuget Reference node like `suggestion 1` and then remain the Project Reference node of `ProjectC`. Keep only the latter.

=========================================

**Answer** updated from **k4st0r42**

Remove all nuget references and project references from **Project A** and then only  add a reference to the local **Project C**.

Comment: You can use conditions in the .csproj file and switch between referencing the project and nuget. We usually generate special solutions for that and have the build server run the tests based on NuGet release code and Project reference code if a shared lib is used